# Export local security policy

Tags: scripting, group-policy

I am trying to export the local security policy on a number of servers into a template file which I can then import into a group policy.  I cna do this manually without issue but I have been unsuccesssful in finding a way to script this process.  Is is possible to script the creation of the export of local security policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible to script the export of the local security database.